# Access SQL Query using BETWEEN Statement and dates from a form

Tags: sql

I'm probably missing something basic here, but I can't for the life of me get this working.

I have a database that is tracking when certain projects are completed, and I want to be able to show in a list the completed projects between a date range.
The date range to check between is set by the user on a form.

I have built a query in Access:

> SELECT Logs.Completed 
>   FROM Logs 
>   WHERE Logs.Completed BETWEEN Forms!UIBrowseCompleted!Text53 AND Forms!UIBrowseCompleted!Text55 
>   ORDER BY Logs.Completed;

I have got the dates formatted in the text box so they are in *#MM/DD/YYYY#* format (I have manually put these dates direct in the query and this works) but when I run the query I get the following error:

> This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated. For example, a numeric expression may contain too many complicated elements. Try simplifying the expression by assigning parts of the expression to variables.

I have tried modifying the query to take the *#* out of the text fields in the form, and including *'* around the Forms!UIBrowseCompleted!Text53 but I've still not got any joy from it.

has anyone had this issue before, or can anyone point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate, please search SO for that error message before asking

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access 2007: Querying for DateTime field between two Short Date values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532077/access-2007-querying-for-datetime-field-between-two-short-date-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want MS Access query or SQL query?
If you want MS Access query then you can try with following

```
SELECT Logs.Completed 
FROM Logs 
WHERE Logs.Completed >= Forms!UIBrowseCompleted!Text53 AND Logs.Completed  <= Forms!UIBrowseCompleted!Text55 
ORDER BY Logs.Completed;
```

Comment: Hi Urvi, Yes it's an Access query that I'm building, I've tried your approach and it works perfectly, thank you so much! It also means I don't have to format the date in the #MM/DD/YYYY# format and can keep it as DD/MM/YYYY which is less coding on the form to work out. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

between query will take time normally we use >= and <= to check date range
like

```
>= Forms!UIBrowseCompleted!Text53 AND Logs.Completed  <= Forms!UIBrowseCompleted
```